# Linked data from database to a button tkinter

Tags: python, database, tkinter, button

I am working on a project on tkinter python.

This is how my graphic interface looks like:

[image]

And I have this database.txt:

```
ChickenCurry,Rice,Curry,Chicken,0.ppm
ChocolateCake,Chocolate,Flour,Sugar,Eggs,1.ppm
BolognesePasta,Pasta,Beef,TomatoeSauce,Cheese,2.ppm
```

Really simple. 0.ppm, 1.ppm and 2.ppm are the name of 3 images, the first one is the image of chicken curry the second one of chocolate and the last one of bolognese pasta.

**My project**: I would like to display the image of the chicken dish when I am clicking on the button ChickenCurry, the image of the chocolate cake when I am clicking on the chocolate cake, etc...

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

class Application(tk.Frame):
    x = 2

def __init__(self, param = None, i = None, master=None):
    super().__init__(master)
    self.master = master
    self.pack()
    self.create_widgets()
    
    
def create_widgets(self):
    

    if (self.x == 2):
        param = "coucou"
    self.hi_there = tk.Label(self)
    self.hi_there["text"] = param
    #self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
    self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

    self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                          command=self.master.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side="bottom")
    
    # Opening file in read format
    File = open('data.txt',"r")
    if(File == None):
        print("File Not Found..")
    else:
        while(True):
            # extracting data from records 
            record = File.readline()
            if (record == ''): break
            data = record.split(',')
            print('Name of the dish:', data[0])
            self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
            self.hi_there["text"] = data[0]
            self.hi_there["command"] = self.photoOfTheDish
            self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
            # printing each record's data in organised form
            for i in range(1, len(data)-1):
                print('Ingredients:',data[i])
                self.hi_there = tk.Label(self)
                self.hi_there["text"] = data[i]
                self.hi_there.pack(side="top")
    File.close()
    
def photoOfTheDish(self):
    novi = Toplevel()
    self.canvas = Canvas(novi, width = 1500, height = 1000)
    self.canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    File = open('data.txt',"r")
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        record = File.readline()
        data = record.split(',')
        gif1 = PhotoImage(file = data[-1].rstrip('\n'))
                                        #image not visual
        self.canvas.create_image(50, 10, image = gif1, anchor = NW)
        #assigned the gif1 to the canvas object
        self.canvas.gif1 = gif1

    
    

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("5000x2000")
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

My issue is whatever the button I am clicking on, it's always the image corresponding to "0.ppm" which is displaying. I don't know how to link the button to his set of value from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `photoOfTheDish()`, you open `data.txt` and read only the first line to get the image filename. Therefore you always get the `0.ppm`.

You can use `lambda` to pass the image filename to `photoOfTheDish()` when creating the buttons:

```py
def create_widgets(self):
    ...
    else:
        while True:
            ...
            # extracting data from records
            record = File.readline().rstrip() # strip out the trailing newline
            ...
            # pass image filename to callback
            self.hi_there["command"] = lambda image=data[-1]: self.photoOfTheDish(image)
            ...
    ...

def photoOfTheDish(self, image):
    novi = Toplevel()
    self.canvas = Canvas(novi, width = 1500, height = 1000)
    self.canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    self.canvas.gif1 = PhotoImage(file=image)
    self.canvas.create_image(50, 10, image=self.canvas.gif1, anchor=NW)
```